# Is it Possible using Terminal to run iOS Application in instrument?

Tags: ios, jenkins, terminal, xcode4.5

I want to run my iPad Application in Instrument for Memory Leak and object Allocation using Terminal.

I have done goggling as well.I know how to open terminal using following command :

`open /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app`

I have tried the following command as well.

```
instruments -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Leaks.tracetemplate" -/Users/iOSRider/Downloads/samplecode/build/Release-iphoneos/sample.app
```

but I am getting following Error:

```
`-[NSAlert alertWithError:] called with `nil NSError.
```

A generic error message will be displayed, but the user deserves better.

Then I have tried

```
instruments -w "cd73f2aadff0726a923b22bc69fdca4420f08ffb" -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Leaks.tracetemplate" -/Users/iOSRider/Downloads/samplecode/build/Release-iphoneos sample.app
```

but I am getting Following Error:

```
Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
```

I have tried the following command as well

```
 instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/iOSRider/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-ejuawqyrosinegcnvzhyrjhxkyue/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sample.app
```

but I am getting New Error Now

```
Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
iOSTeam:~ iOSRider$ 
iOSTeam:~ iOSRider$ instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/iOSRider/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-ejuawqyrosinegcnvzhyrjhxkyue/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sample.app
2013-06-27 17:02:44.103 instruments[15986:1603] -[NSAlert alertWithError:] called with nil NSError. A generic error message will be displayed, but the user deserves better.


2013-06-27 17:09:03.530 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6dbc2390>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.530 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.capabilities"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6db89130>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.530 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6dbc2a50>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.531 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.filebrowser"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6dbb8da0>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.531 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.deviceinfo"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6db8ead0>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.531 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6dbc3740>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.532 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.wireless"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6dbbcfb0>
2013-06-27 17:09:03.532 instruments[15986:7877] Connection peer refused channel request for "com.apple.instruments.server.services.mobilenotifications"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7fde6dbbe050>
```

I want to run Instruments from Jenkins, that's why I am testing in Terminal.

I am using an iPad 2 with iOS 6.1.3. I am okay if it works in Simulator as well.

Please guide me on this if I am making any mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a specific device ID (`[-w device]`). Although the template might have it, I think you need to specify it anyways at a command line.

I did a bit of googling around and found [this article](http://shaune.com.au/automated-ui-testing-for-ios-apps-uiautomation-jasmine-jenkins/).

Here's a paired down script based on that article that you could use to run Instruments from a command line.

*runTests.sh*

```
XCODE_PATH=`xcode-select -print-path`
TRACETEMPLATE="$XCODE_PATH/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate"
APP_LOCATION=$2
DEVICE_ID=$3

if [ ! $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "You must specify the app location and the test file."
    echo "\t (optionally supply unique device ID of physical iOS device)"
    echo "\t eg. ./build.sh suite.js <xcodeproject directory>/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app <device-udid>"
    exit -1
fi

# If running on device, only need name of app, full path not important
if [ ! "$DEVICE_ID" = "" ]; then
  RUN_ON_SPECIFIC_DEVICE_OPTION="-w $DEVICE_ID"
  APP_LOCATION=`basename $APP_LOCATION`
fi

# Kick off the instruments build
instruments \
$RUN_ON_SPECIFIC_DEVICE_OPTION \
-t $TRACETEMPLATE \
$APP_LOCATION \
-e UIARESULTSPATH /var/tmp
```

Source: [here](https://github.com/shaune/jasmine-ios-acceptance-tests)

Comment: it's only working in Simulator.Is there any chance for testing memory leak directly in device?